# Reading permissions on OneDrive item gives wrong invitedBy facet

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using [this documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/permissions.htm) to query the Microsoft Graph API. Given an item ID, I am getting the permissions for that item. This is for a personal OneDrive account.

An example of an API call I make would be:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/D50E00A756B729AA!159/permissions`

I am returned a permissions list like the following:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "grantedTo": {
                "user": {
                    "displayName": "Joe Smith",
                    "id": "bada17275094e9b0"
                }
            },
            "id": "nm4tYSpLz13yR39343yrz0WZXWo",
            "invitation": {
                "email": "joe.smith@hotmail.com",
                "invitedBy": {
                    "user": {
                        "id": "joe.smith@hotmail.com"
                    }
                },
                "signInRequired": false
            },
            "inheritedFrom": {
                "driveId": "d50e00a756b729aa",
                "id": "D50E00A756B729AA!155",
                "name": "Test",
                "path": "/drive/root:/Test",
                "shareId": "s!AKopt1anAA7VgRs"
            },
            "link": {
                "webUrl": "https://1drv.ms/u/s!BKopt1anAA7VgR9yuy10rsiYA_7Q"
            },
            "roles": [
                "write"
            ],
            "shareId": "s!BKopt1anAA7VgRtyuy10rsiYA_7Q",
            "expirationDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "grantedTo": {
                "user": {
                    "displayName": "Joe Smith",
                    "id": "45aa3379f269b493"
                }
            },
            "id": "UJX2eUiHYJs7acen2EcvmrGCsf4",
            "invitation": {
                "email": "foo-bar@outlook.com",
                "invitedBy": {
                    "user": {
                        "id": "foo-bar@outlook.com"
                    }
                },
                "signInRequired": false
            },
            "inheritedFrom": {
                "driveId": "d50e00a756b729aa",
                "id": "D50E00A756B729AA!155",
                "name": "Test",
                "path": "/drive/root:/Test",
                "shareId": "s!AKopt1anAA7VgRs"
            },
            "link": {
                "webUrl": "https://1drv.ms/u/s!BKopt1anAA7VgR8mG0ye7kE5Dtp1"
            },
            "roles": [
                "write"
            ],
            "shareId": "s!BKopt1anAA7VgRsmG0ye7kE5Dtp1",
            "expirationDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "grantedTo": {
                "user": {
                    "displayName": "Joe Smith",
                    "id": "bada17275094e9b0"
                }
            },
            "id": "t3QbXwuwNlmJCKF18R1Vwrp_I_U",
            "invitation": {
                "email": "joe.smith@hotmail.com",
                "invitedBy": {
                    "user": {
                        "id": "joe.smith@hotmail.com"
                    }
                },
                "signInRequired": false
            },
            "inheritedFrom": {
                "driveId": "d50e00a756b729aa",
                "id": "D50E00A756B729AA!160",
                "shareId": "s!AKopt1anAA7VgSA"
            },
            "link": {
                "webUrl": "https://1drv.ms/u/s!BKopt1anAA7VgR-0ZrUC-a2mYpgl"
            },
            "roles": [
                "write"
            ],
            "shareId": "s!BKopt1anAA7VgSC0ZrUC-a2mYpgl",
            "expirationDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you look in any of those permissions, you will see that the `invitedTo` facet always returns the user which the permission was granted to. I used test accounts and verified that what I just said is true. This seems like a bug.

Is there any answer for why this is happening? I would expect `invitedBy` to be the user who issued the permission to the person being granted it. So instead of Joe Smith being the `grantedTo` user, the invitation email and the `invitedBy` user, we should have a completely separate user in `invitedBy`.

Comment: I'll need to do some testing but the property names certainly imply the behavior you're expecting here. The descriptions in the docs are pretty vague however. I assume you are trying to find "who shared this with me"?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Yes that's correct. To be clear, it's "Who shared this file with <user_from_grantedTo>?"

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this, I'm actually getting _nothing_ back for permissions on a remote item. I can however see who shared it with me via the `shared` element in the `remoteItem` facet.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I am not referring to remoteItems. I am referring to items in my drive. Let's say I have a file and share it with someone. What should appear in the permissions for that item? I expected `invitedBy` to have my user and `grantedTo` to have the user I shared it with. But I guess if someone shares my drive item with someone else, then `invitedBy` should include the user who shared my file. Is it even possible to share someone else's file as long as it was shared with you first? If not, is it safe to assume that `invitedBy` on one of my files should always be me?